# I create 2 independant app with rails, but they are using same DB! (mysql)?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I have two folders with 2 differents apps rails.
I want use mysql with both, so I use same database.yml configuration, but the second app do not create their own "db/development.mysql", and after "rake db:migrate", schema.rb include now migration of my first app and the second...

How can I use separate mysql db for my 2 apps?

thx.

Comment: setup own DB names in `database.yml`

Comment: First rule of using shared database - make migrations only in one place

Comment: MySql is not sqlite (which generates local file DB). MySql has "global" DB in system

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mysql is not installed locally to your project, but gloabally for your system.

So when you specify mysql2 as the database adapter, you should not expect to have anything like `db/some_db.mysql` to exist.

In mysql you can have different databases, each one containing an arbitrary set of tables (table names can be the same between databases, i.e., you can have a `users` table in each of them).

In your `database.yml` you have to write a different database name for each project

In your first app:

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  username: your_user
  password: your_password
  database: first_app_dbname
  encoding: utf8
```

in the second:

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  username: your_user
  password: your_password
  database: second_app_dbname
  encoding: utf8
```